# Sorting of integer element without using existing algorithm or sorting technique

Tags: java, c

If i have 1 core integers  elements in arrays  which having only 0,1 in random manner. & i want to sort this array without using existing algorithm. or sorting method and using minimal iteration.

How i can do that..
please help me out.

Comment: I don't understand "1 core integers elements". Can you clarify?

Comment: *I want to sort this array without using existing algorithms*: Well, it seems difficult to not use an algorithm, or please tell us what is an algorithm for you.

Comment: @pbabcdefp , I guess it is "1 crore integer elements"

Comment: @CoolGuy Thank you. I'd never heard the word crore before.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. I am assuming you have an array of integers, each integer being either 0 or 1, and no other data. To "sort" it, simply count the number of 0s and 1s in the array, e.g. N zeros and M ones. Then overwrite the array, by writing out N zeros and M ones (or vice versa, depending on whether you want to "sort" in ascending or descending order). This is an O(n) algorithm: one pass to count, one pass to re-write.

Comment: its 1 lac elements....

Answer (score 0):

method 1:count all 0's and then set it from the front and then set 1's size - count(0) times.

method 2: Start from both ends of the array and swap 1s from left to 0s in right until reach the middle of the array.

```
while (begin < end) {
      // If find 0 at left, keep moving
      if (0 == toSort[begin]) {
        begin++;

      }
      // if a 1 occurs at left, move from right until find a zero
      else if (1 == toSort[end]) {
        end--;
      }
      // Here we found a 1 at left and 0 at right, so swap
      else {
        toSort[begin] = 0;
        toSort[end] = 1;
      }
    }
```

time complexity: O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can count the number of 0 and 1 and create a new array with the same amount of 0 and 1 but choosing the order you add them.